# System notification service error

Tags: applications, notifications

Getting this error from system notification service. With two options, Keep it anyway (unsafe) or disable. I'm getting this notification in every 2 minutes. No matter if I select disable, or keep it anyway (unsafe).

I have restored my phone to its original factory settings two times, still the same issue.
 [image]

[image]

Comment: Please modify your question with  your device name and android version.

Answer (score 0):

That's the warning from Google Play Protect, which is quite new. It's detecting that app to be harmful, but often it detects some system apps as harmful (which are not available in play store). So if that app is a system app, then nothing to worry about. But if you don't wanna seen the warnings then go over to play store and disable both options in play protect. You can find that option in the left navigation bar....

[image: disable the options you're seeing in this image]

Comment: Phone Model : GIONEE F103 Pro, Version : V6517